ApacheConnectorProvider : Jersey Client using proxy failf with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
I'm tryng to use Jersey to build a client and it works.
But I'm not able to connect via a proxy server.
I have tried to use sugestion found in
ApacheConnectorProvider : Jersey Client 2.5.1
but I get an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
Here is my code
        ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
        configuration = configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        //maximum time of inactivity between two data packets
        configuration = configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, READ_TIMEOUT);
        
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50699520/proxy-setting-not-working-in-jersey-clientconfig
        configuration.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
        configuration = configuration.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "http://localhost:8000");
          

        
        
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
        webTarget = client.target(REST_URI);


